# How can I load a KML in google map, without changing the map center

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

**How would I add the KML as a layer in google maps (javascript v3) without changing the map extent/zoom?**

I am adding a KML which has several events all over the world, because of this google maps javascript v3 changes the map extent to a very large zoomed out view.

Here is some example code:

```
function loadOverlay(inc) 
{
    var overlay = new google.maps.KmlLayer(inc);
    overlay.setMap(map);
    overlayArray.push(overlay);
}

function initialize_gmap()
{
    var Rochester = new google.maps.LatLng(43.1561, -77.607); 
    var myOptions = {
    zoom: 11,
    center: Rochester,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
    }

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
}

//Then i initialize the map here, and load the kml
initialize_gmap();
loadOverlay("linktokml.kml");
```

After the kml is loaded it goes to a very large zoom to show all the locations in the kml. 
How would I either prevent this, or go back to my initial extent/zoom?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just set `preserveViewport` option of [google.maps.KmlLayerOptions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#KmlLayerOptions) to `true`:

```
var overlay = new google.maps.KmlLayer(inc,{preserveViewport:true});
```